# Jekyll For Loop Questions

Tags: jekyll, liquid, static-site

So I want to setup a for loop in Jekyll that only displays the latest event/item in the collection. (Organised by date)

Currently, this doesn't do much apart from sort the date by weight and cycle through the collection with a limit of one.

```
    {% assign sorted_events = site.events | sort: "date" %}
    {% for event in sorted_events limit:1 %}
    <section class="venue-info wow fadeIn" data-wow-duration="1.2s" id="about">
        <div class="upcoming-event">
          <h1>Our Next Event</h1>
        <h2>{{ event.title }}</h2>
        <p>{{ event.description }}</p>
        <a class="btn scroll" href="{{ event.url }}">Learn More</a>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: How can I organise it by date, it states it in the question.

Comment: How are your dates defined? An item of the collection as an example would be helpful.

Comment: Listed in front matter as 

---
title: example
date: 2017-01-17
---
content

Answer (score 0):

Taking `{{site.post}}` as the collection for this example, we sort the collection of posts and then use the *last* tag to get the last element of the array.

- To get the **newest** post:

  ```
  {% assign newest = site.posts | sort: "date" | last  %}

  {{newest.title}}
  {{newest.date}}
  ```
- **oldest** post:

  ```
  {% assign oldest = site.posts | sort: "date" | first  %}

  {{oldest.title}}
  {{oldest.date}}
  ```

It should work for any other collection like `site.events` as your code refers.